# How to create a project that combines a EF4 class library with an EF7 .net core class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, architecture, webforms

My current .net visual studio solution looks like:

1. Data - class library, .net 4.8 with EF4
2. asp.net webforms .net 4.8 - references Data

We're building a new asp.net core website, so our solution is going to end up like:

1. Data - class library, .net 4.8 with EF4
2. DataCore - class library, .net 6 with EF Core 7
3. asp.net webforms .net 4.8 - references Data
4. asp.net core .net 6 - references DataCore

Both Data and DataCore are pointed to the same database and contain all the linq statements for all CRUD etc.

I dont want to be duplicating linq code / methods in the Data projects. Is there a way of architecting this solution to avoid this. I should note that the Data and asp.net webforms projects are significant in size and converting the webforms project to .net core is not an option.

Comment: transition completely to asp.net core, and abandon your webforms project? There is no way to use EF Core 7 in .net framework. The closest you can do is a EF Core 3, that should be usable in both .net framework and .net Core.

Comment: Use a NET 6 standard library project to house your Data and DataCore libraries. The choice will be yours whether or not to dupe the classes or use preprocessing conditional statements throughout. I personally dupe my dbcontexts and entities due to the vast differences in c# versions (ie: nullable reference types). Classes like services or business layers can easily be used in both EF versions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JonasH, although I cant abandon our webforms project we've gone down this route:

1 - .Net Standard 2.0 Class Library, EF CORE 3.1

2 - .Net 4.8 Class Library, EF 6

3 - ASP.NET CORE 6 Razor Web Project, references 1

4 - ASP.NET Webforms .net 4.8, references 1 & 2

Any database stuff etc for the Razor project and anything shared between the web projects has been moved into the .net standard class library.

For anyone interested we follow a database first approach and we used 'EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator' by Simon Hughes in our .net standard project because it can be setup to run EF Core 3.1 (which you need in this case), We've used EF Core Power Tools in the past but it does not let you target 3.1.

This also allows us to have 2 sets of EF so I don't have to move all my old CRUD / Queries etc over to the new project straight away